# insert values ​to a table in mongodb with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I created a table in mongodb and I want to add values ​​to it via nodejs, this is my code:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/attendances', { useNewUrlParser: true });
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const dataSchema = new Schema({ userId: String, date: Date, start: Date,end:Date });
const dataModel = mongoose.model("datas",dataSchema);
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error',  console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
console.log('connect to DB');
});



router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
const {userId,date,start} = req.body;
console.log('add',userId,date,start);
dataModel.create({userId:userId,date:date,start:start},function (err, result) {
});
dataModel.findOne({userId:userId,date:new Date().toDateString()},function(err,result){
  console.log('findOne',result);
  res.end(result);
  })
});
```

He does not add my values ​​to the table.
Where's my mistake?

This is my err:

```
Error: datas validation failed: start: Cast to date failed for value 
"11:56:26" at path "start"
```

Comment: What is the value of start variable

Answer (score 0):

There is a more than one mistake.

First:
Your Object Validation fails. I need to know whats inside your start variable.

Second:
You use two different dates one is *date* variable other one is generated by querying with *date:new Date().toDateString()*

Third:
Javascript works asynchronously. You cannot know when your findOne triggers after object successfully created.